# [NSPopupButton performClick]: menuDidClose: not being called immediately

Tags: objective-c, macos, appkit

I use -[NSPopupButton performClick:nil] to programmatically popup the menu of an NSPopupButton.

Even though the delegate of the NSPopupButton's menu is correctly set, the delegate's menuDidClose: method is not get called, when the menu get dismissed by clicking outside the menu. 
This delegate is method called after the next mouse click on the NSPopupButton instance, though.

(Background: I'm trying to add an "Edit Mode" to a potentially long popup menu, where the user can enabled/disable checkboxes to hide particular items. Once the user chooses the "Edit this menu' command, I'd like to popup it up again in said edit mode.)

Comment: Are you replacing or editing the menu? Post a [mre] please.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, use [NSMenu popupContextMenu:withEvent:forView] to display another menu over the original popup button (like a cave man.)

```
- (IBAction) showHidePopupAction:(id) sender
{
     NSRect  frame = self.shippingServicePopup.frame;

    NSPoint location = [self convertPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMinX(frame),
                                                  NSMaxY(frame))
                               toView:self.window.contentView];

    NSEvent *fakeEvent = [NSEvent mouseEventWithType:NSEventTypeLeftMouseDown
                                        location:location
                                   modifierFlags:0
                                       timestamp:[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
                                    windowNumber:self.window.windowNumber
                                         context:nil
                                     eventNumber:0
                                      clickCount:1
                                        pressure:1];

    [NSMenu popUpContextMenu:self.editModeMenu withEvent:fakeEvent forView:self];
}
```

Comment: Careful. At least in the old days, "context menu" meant any Services registered to be shown in contextual menus may be automatically added to your menu. I think they added another call to pop up a menu that doesn't add services anymore (or takes a flag?), try using that instead.